# How can I revert my last push on hub.docker.com?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have damaged my working docker image by pushing and overwriting by a faulty docker image on hub.docker.com. How can I revert the last push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no revert option that I'm aware of. If you have a good copy of your image somewhere, you can repush that to the registry. To avoid this issue in the future, follow one or more of these steps:

1. Avoid using the latest tag and give each build a unique tag.
2. Use a reproducible build process with a Dockerfile that is saved in version control which uses specific versions for all dependencies. This allows you to checkout a previous state of the Dockerfile to rerun a previous build.
3. Maintain a private registry of your own for your images and any dependencies you have on other images. Make sure to maintain those dependencies (updating periodically) and backup your registry.

Comment: after encountering such a blunder, I am definitely going to use different tags. But docker hub should think about the functionality of reverting a push. :(

Comment: docker push should reject updating a tag unless you force it to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Advanced Image Management page in docker hub to copy the digest of the good image, pull it to your system, overwrite the tag, then push back. Use these commands:

```
docker image pull myname/example@sha256:1234
docker tag myname/example@sha256:1234 myname/example:mytag
docker push myname/example:mytag
```

Assuming `myname/example@sha256:1234` is your copied digest of the good image from docker hub, `myname/example:mytag` is what you want to tag the image as.